# How do I make an Access 2016 crosstab output columns generic?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to compare two years' worth of budgets. Years range from 2020 to 2028 (say). I need the crosstab report-driving query to be able to output "Year1" and "Year2" rather than say 2021 & 2022

I have already created the crosstab query which will drive a report but the test was comparing 2027 and 2028. This meant that the output columns have been hard-coded to 2027 & 2028. As I wish to ask the user for any pair of years in the year range, I cannot have a report that refers to "2027" or "2028", it must just refer to "Year1" and "Year2".

I've scratched my head on this and tried to type column headings "Year1" and "Year2" but of course this gives an error.

Is what I wish to do possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Period2 column that calculates something like:

```
Period2: iif(period = dmax("period", "mytable"), "Current", "Previous")
```

Probably not superfast but you get the idea.
You could achieve a similar result with perhaps a better performance by creating (and joining) a subquery like

```
select Min(period) as Previous, max(period) as Current from myMainTable
```

You can then use this Period2 as the Column header in your xtab.

Comment: I see where you're coming from Patrick. However, I have to use a crosstab because in the Budget Transactions table (upon which this is all based) "Account Year" is just a column with a year value in it for each Budget transaction record. The key is to be able to somehow call the two Output year columns Year1 & Year2 rather than 2027 & 2028 as a hard coded solution.
Personally, I'm sceptical as to whether this is even possible but I'm sure it would help me and a lot of other peeps if it was ;-)

Comment: My suggestion IS the necessary step to create a crosstab. Periods will become the column header.